# Ebook reader similar to Kobo Desktop for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ebooks

Now when I say ebook reader, I mean something that can view PDF and EPUB files but still maintain the level of design that [Kobo Desktop](http://www.kobo.com/desktop) has.

I am looking for software that can be used with Ubuntu. Preferably free and open-source, but not a requirement.

Some features I am looking for:

- A library to view books
- Easily add books to your library
- Display the covers of books nicely in the library
- Bookmarks
- Page notes
- Ability to sync with a connected ebook device (not a requirement)
- In-app dictionary (if possible)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) is a very popular ebook management software.
It fulfills all of your requirements, barring in-app dictionary.

I will draw particular notice to the ability to drag and drop ebook files in to the application to add them to your library. This works great and I use it all the time.

Beyond that, its other notable features are the ability to subscribe to periodical webfeeds, and have them made into ebooks.
It also has a very powerful ability to convert between formats.

It is also available as an [ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/calibre), though it is quite out of date,
it is still very functional (and should meet all your requirements).
The author recommends using the version from his site.